Uniquness of a record containing a collection
I am using C# records in a HashSet to enforce uniqueness. This works well, but as soon as the record contains a Collection then it stops working.
ie. this passes:
public record Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

HashSet<Person> uniquePeople = new();
uniquePeople.Add(new Person { FirstName = "John" });
uniquePeople.Add(new Person { FirstName = "John" });
Assert.That(uniquePeople.Count() == 1);

But this fails:
public record Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public HashSet<int> FavouriteNumbers { get; set; } = new();
}

HashSet<Person> uniquePeople = new();
uniquePeople.Add(new Person { FirstName = "John" });
uniquePeople.Add(new Person { FirstName = "John" });
Assert.That(uniquePeople.Count() == 1);

How can I enforce uniqueness on nested collections using records?

Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67662645

You'll find it's not just collections, but any property that is complex (is an object rather than than a value). You may find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64326511/3043 But the short version is the HashSet type does NOT have anything at all built in to do an equivalence check between two instances. You'll have to write that code yourself.

Did you try implementing your own IEqualityComparer<Person>?

@SomeBody it looks like that's the only option. i was hoping to avoid it

It's not necessary to use a class, one can define a custom Equals() for a record.  See Custom Equality check for C# 9 records and https://dotnetfiddle.net/td7CCa

You want custom Equals and GetHashCode since you want to compare FavouriteNumbers as sets, not as references; that's why I suggest turning record (which has its own implementation of these methods) into class:
// Note class, not record
public class Person : IEquatable<Person> {
  public string FirstName { get; set; }
  public HashSet<int> FavouriteNumbers { get; set; } = new();

  public override int GetHashCode() =>
    HashCode.Combine(FirstName, FavouriteNumbers.Count);

  public bool Equals(Person? other) => other is not null &&
    string.Equals(FirstName, other.FirstName) &&
    FavouriteNumbers.SetEquals(other.FavouriteNumbers);

  public override bool Equals(object? obj) => Equals(obj as Person);

  public override string ToString() => $"{FirstName}";
}

If you have to deal with record (you can't change it), you can implement custom comparer:
public sealed class PersonEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Person> {
  public bool Equals(Person? x, Person? y) {
    if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
      return true;
    if (x is null || y is null)
      return false;

    return string.Equals(x.FirstName, y.FirstName) &&
           x.FavouriteNumbers.SetEquals(y.FavouriteNumbers);
  }

  public int GetHashCode(Person obj) =>
    obj is null ? 0 : HashCode.Combine(obj.FirstName, obj.FavouriteNumbers.Count);
}

and then use it:
// note PersonEqualityComparer
HashSet<Person> uniquePeople = new(new PersonEqualityComparer());

uniquePeople.Add(new Person { FirstName = "John" });
uniquePeople.Add(new Person { FirstName = "John" });


It's not necessary to use a class, one can define a custom Equals() for a record.  See Custom Equality check for C# 9 records and https://dotnetfiddle.net/td7CCa

@dbc: Even if it's possible to declare Equals(Person? other) for record, I doubt if we should do it like this (record implements its own Equals which can conflict with our one)

Agree a custom comparer would be a better solution but using a custom Equals() is explicitly allowed by the language docs: To implement value equality, the compiler synthesizes several methods, including:... A virtual, or sealed, Equals(R? other) where R is the record type. This method implements IEquatable. This method can be declared explicitly.

As explained in the docs for record, if you supply an implementation for Equals(Person? other) the compiler will use that instead of generating its own:

To implement value equality, the compiler synthesizes several methods, including:

A virtual, or sealed, Equals(R? other) where R is the record type. This method implements IEquatable<T>. This method can be declared explicitly.

An override of Object.GetHashCode(). This method can be declared explicitly.



That being said, MSFT also explicitly recommends against overriding Equals() for mutable types.  From System.Object.Equals method: Guidelines for value types:

You should not override Equals on a mutable reference type. This is because overriding Equals requires that you also override the GetHashCode method, as discussed in the previous section. This means that the hash code of an instance of a mutable reference type can change during its lifetime, which can cause the object to be lost in a hash table.

Thus if you to use content equality for your FavouriteNumbers set, you should eliminate the setters for your properties and also use ImmutableHashSet<int> instead of HashSet<int>:
using System.Collections.Immutable;

public record Person(string FirstName, ImmutableHashSet<int> FavouriteNumbers)
{
    public Person(string FirstName, IEnumerable<int> FavouriteNumbers) : this(FirstName, ImmutableHashSet.CreateRange(FavouriteNumbers)) { }
    
    // Use of HashCode.Combine() suggested by Dmitry Bychenko in https://stackoverflow.com/a/78419565
    public override int GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine(FirstName, FavouriteNumbers?.Count);
    
    //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#value-equality
    public virtual bool Equals(Person? other) => 
        object.ReferenceEquals(other, this)
        || (!object.ReferenceEquals(other, null) && this.GetType() == other.GetType() && this.FirstName == other.FirstName && this.FavouriteNumbers.SetEquals(other.FavouriteNumbers));

    protected virtual bool PrintMembers(StringBuilder sb)
    {
        //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/record#printmembers-formatting-in-derived-records
        //Make FavouriteNumbers be printed as a comma-separated list of values.
        sb.Append(nameof(FirstName)).Append(" = ").Append(FirstName)
            .Append(", ")
            .Append(nameof(FavouriteNumbers)).Append(" = ").AppendJoin(',', FavouriteNumbers);
        return true;
    }
}

And then you can do e.g.:
var person = new Person("Foo", new [] { 1, 2, 3 });

var modifiedPerson = person with { 
    FavouriteNumbers = person.FavouriteNumbers.Remove(3).Add(5) 
};

Demo fiddle here.
If you require Person to be mutable, you should not use a custom implementation for Equals() and instead you should create a custom IEqualityComparer<Person> as shown in this answer by Dmitry Bychenko.
